# Is there a way to insert a string into the the statement ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable._____) in order to retrieve an image?

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView and I want it to display an image from my drawable folder based on the value
of a number. I have a collection of images of playing cards in my drawable folder and I'm making a game where each card represents a number from 1 to 52. To represent this, I made a hashmap that links each number from 1 to 52 to a string which is the full name of the png file in my drawable folder. Now I need to find a way to use this key-value link in my hashmap to display a card in my ImageView depending on what my number variable is. The issue I've run into is that I don't know how to use the string value from the hashmap to access the image.

The statement that changes the image should look like this

```
    dealt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubsace);
```

Where dealt2 is the ImageView variable.

I've checked and this works, but what I'm trying to do is something like:

dealt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cards.get(1));

Where cards is my hashmap and cards.get(1) will return the string "clubsace.png". I don't know if there is a way to turn this string into something that can fit into that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dealt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubsace);` is equivalent to the following:

```
dealt2.setImageResource(dealt2.getResources().getIdentifier("clubsace", "drawable", dealt2.getContext().getPackageName()));
```

And please don't forget to remove `.png` from the hashmap

Comment: Thanks a lot, no way I was figuring this one out by myself

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way can be to just store the drawable resource id into the HashMap instead of just the image name.

This is due to the fact that all the resources are mapped to `Integer`. i.e. `R.drawable.clubsace` has `Integer` type so you can store it in `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> cards = new HashMap<>();
cards.put(1, R.drawable.clubsace);
```

Then you can simply set the resource directly.

```
dealt2.setImageResource(cards.get(1));
```